# GetExportedTypes() exception for ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom

Tags: c#

I am getting an error in a piece of code in our framework which I have no idea how to solve.

Basically, we have a list of dlls via Directory.GetFiles("*.dll"), and when iterating over the list and doing Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(filename).GetExportedTypes(), I get an exception : "Method 'abc' has no implementation".

The method is question is implemented in the assembly used in ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom().

I noticed that the method implements an interface which is in another assembly that is also in the list obtained by Directory.GetFiles(). I reordered the list (i.e so that it is in reverse order, so that the interface assembly is reflected first) but I still get the same error.

Any ideas where to look?

JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the third party components I am using had some assemblies targeting 3.5 and others targeting 4. Now all are targeting 3.5, the problem has disappeared.